# External interface and Internet Explorer 9 issue

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-9, actionscript-2, externalinterface

Boy-oh-boy do I hate external interface.  I have a video player that utilizes external interface to control the flash object and to allow the flash object to pass messages to the same javascript.  For a time it worked well in all browsers.  Then a few days ago i went to go test it in all browsers before i moved the project out of development, and found that the application broke in internet explorer 9.  The following error appeared in the console:

```
SCRIPT16389: Could not complete the operation due to error 8070000c.
jquery.min.js, line 16 character 29366
```

My javascript file is really long but here are the important parts.  All my actions are contained in an object that i created.  Inside one of my methods i have the following lines:

```
var that = this;
that.stop();
```

here are all the methods that get called as a result of that method:

```
this.stop = function(){
    var that = this;
    console.log('stop called');
    that.pause();
    that.seek(0);
    that.isPlaying = false;
    console.log('stop finished');
};

this.pause = function(){  
    var that = this;
        console.log('pause called');
    if(that.player == 'undefined' || that.player == null){
        that.player = that.GetMediaObject(that.playerID);
    }
    that.player.pauseMedia(); //external interface call
    that.isPlaying = false;
    console.log('pause finished');
};

this.seek = function(seek){                 
    var that = this;
    console.log('seek called');
    if(that.player == 'undefined' || that.player ==null){
        console.log("player="+that.player+".  resetting player object");
        that.player = that.GetMediaObject(that.playerID);
        console.log("player="+that.player);
    }
    that.player.scrubMedia(seek); //external interface call

    console.log('seek finished');            
};

//this method returns a reference to my player.  This method is call once when the page loads and then again as necessary by all methods that make external interface calls
this.GetMediaObject = function(playerID){
    var mediaObj = swfobject.getObjectById(playerID);
        console.log('fetching media object: ' +mediaObj );

        //if swfobject.getObjectById fails  
        if(typeof mediaObj == 'undefined' || mediaObj == null){
                console.log('secondary fetch required');
        var isIE = navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/i);
        mediaObj = isIE ? window[playerID] : document[playerID];
    }

    return mediaObj;
};
```

Here's the output from my console.log statments:

```
LOG: fetching media object: [object HTMLObjectElement] 
LOG: video-obj-1: ready 
LOG: stop called 
LOG: pause called 
LOG: pause finished 
LOG: seek called 
LOG: player=[object HTMLObjectElement] 
SCRIPT16389: Could not complete the operation due to error 8070000c. 
jquery.min.js, line 16 character 29366
```

The interesting thing is that it appears that the first external interface call 'that.player.pauseMedia()' doesn't have any issue, but the subsequent call to 'that.player.scrubMedia(0)' fails.  Another odd thing is that it points to jquery as the source of the error, but there's no call to jquery in those functions.

Here's what i know it's not.  It is not an issue where my timing is off.  The last line of my actionscript sends a message to the javascript when the flash object has completely loaded.  Also i set the parameter 'allowScriptAccess' to 'always' so it's not that either.  The actionscript file we use has been used in previous projects so i am 90% certain that that is not the issue.

here's my actionscript anyways.  I didn't write actionscript and i'm not too familiar with the language but I tried to put in the parts that seemed most pertinent to my application:

```
flash.system.Security.allowDomain("*.mydomain.com");

import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

// variables to store local information about the current media
var mediaEmbedServer:String = "www";
var mediaPlayerID:String;
var mediaFile:String;
var mediaDuration:Number;

// variables to be watched by actionscript and message javascript on changes
var mediaPositions:String = "0,0"; // buffer position, scrub position
var mediaStatus:String;

var netStreamClient:Object = new Object();
netStreamClient.onMetaData = metaDataHandler;
netStreamClient.onCuePoint = cuePointHandler;

var connection:NetConnection;
var stream:NetStream;
var media:Video = new Video();

// grab the media's duration when it becomes available
function metaDataHandler(info:Object):void {
mediaDuration = info.duration;
}

function cuePointHandler(info:Object):void {
}

connection = new NetConnection();
connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
connection.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);

try {
var paramName:String;
var paramValue:String;
var paramObject:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
for (paramName in paramObject) {
paramValue = String(paramObject[paramName]);
switch (paramName){
case "server":
mediaEmbedServer = paramValue;
break
case "playerID":
mediaPlayerID = paramValue;
break
}
}
} catch (error:Error) {
}

if (mediaEmbedServer == "dev" || mediaEmbedServer == "dev2"){
connection.connect("rtmp://media.developmentMediaServer.com/myApp");
} else {
connection.connect("rtmp://media.myMediaServer.com/myApp");
}

function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
}  

function connectStream():void {
stream = new NetStream(connection);
stream.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);
stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
stream.client = netStreamClient;
media.attachNetStream(stream);
media.width = 720;
media.height = 405;
addChild(media);
}

function netStatusHandler(stats:NetStatusEvent){
switch (stats.info.code){
case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
connectStream();
break;
case "NetConnection.Call.BadVersion":
case "NetConnection.Call.Failed":
case "NetConnection.Call.Prohibited":
case "NetConnection.Connect.AppShutdown":
case "NetConnection.Connect.Failed":
case "NetConnection.Connect.InvalidApp":
case "NetConnection.Connect.Rejected":
case "NetGroup.Connect.Failed":
case "NetGroup.Connect.Rejected":
case "NetStream.Connect.Failed":
case "NetStream.Connect.Rejected":
case "NetStream.Failed":
case "NetStream.Play.Failed":
case "NetStream.Play.FileStructureInvalid":
case "NetStream.Play.NoSupportedTrackFound":
case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
case "NetStream.Seek.Failed":
case "NetStream.Seek.InvalidTime":
// report error status and reset javascriptPlay
clearInterval(progressInterval);
messageStatus("error");
break;
default:
// check time through file to determine if media is over
if (stream.time > 0 && stream.time >= (mediaDuration - .25)){
// reset media if it has ended
clearInterval(progressInterval);
stream.play(mediaFile, 0, 0);
messageStatus("finished");
}
}
};

var progressInterval:Number;

// respond to a play/pause request by playing/pausing the current stream
function pauseMedia(){
clearInterval(progressInterval);
if (mediaStatus == 'playing'){
stream.pause();
messageStatus("paused");
}
};
ExternalInterface.addCallback( "pauseMedia", pauseMedia );

// respond to a scrub request by seeking to a position in the media
function scrubMedia(newPosition){
clearInterval(progressInterval);
if (mediaStatus == "playing"){
stream.pause();
messageStatus("paused");
}
stream.seek(newPosition * mediaDuration);
var positionSeconds = newPosition * mediaDuration;
messagePositions(positionSeconds+","+positionSeconds);
};
ExternalInterface.addCallback( "scrubMedia", scrubMedia );


ExternalInterface.call("MediaPlayerReady", mediaPlayerID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an [undefined expando property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622931) which may be caused by a [jQuery IE9 bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8485). The best way to debug it is to remove the userAgent test and replace it with a check for the object element, such as:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("object")[0].outerHTML
```

to see whether the ID attribute is being changed after the first click by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using JPEGCam, which also uses flash's external interface. My webcam control was being loaded dynamically within a div, and would then throw this error in IE (not firefox or chrome). After moving the initialization of my flash control to document.ready in  the parent page, then hiding/showing/moving the control as needed, i was able to work around this exception.

Hope that helps.