# Uploadify error 8070000c. Only in IE Browser

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, uploadify

While using jQuery uploadify, I got an error:

```
SCRIPT16389: Could not complete the operation due to error 8070000c.
jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.js, line 292 character 5
```

from the second attempt onwards. This is only happening for IE browser.  Any solutions?

Comment: Error code looks weird, could it be `8007000c`?

Answer (score 2):

According to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12060034/855738) found here, on StackOverflow, it seems to be [a jQuery bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8485) that causes an [undefined expando property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622931). You can find some more information on the previosly linked sites, as well as the solution.

It might also be [related to Flash](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/323#issuecomment-2424012), which I understand it's also used by jQuery uploadify as an alternative to HTML5.

For future reference, in cases like these I search for either the error code (in this case *8070000c*) or the short description of the error message (ex. *Could not complete the operation due to error 8070000c*) on either [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=Could%20not%20complete%20the%20operation%20due%20to%20error%208070000c&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest) or [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=8070000c&submit=search) and usually I always find some relevant info

Comment: For what it is worth: I get this in relation to [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard). Also only in IE (both 8, 9 and 10).